# Programa en python para buscar cameos en una oración

Tags: python

Debo hacer un programa en python el cual al entrar una oración como por ejemplo:
*Mientras sufria de sarampion asaba nueces en el magosto.* Encuentre la cantidad de veces que aparace **saramago** dentro de esa oración.

Por ejemplo: En esta oración *Mientra**s** sufri**a** de sa**ram**pion **a**saba nueces en el ma**go**sto.*
se puede encontrar **saramago** una ves en la letras que se ven resaltadas.

He intentado con ciclos y guardando las letras en listas, pero no he logrado hacer el programa.
¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la recomendación, es la primera pregunta que hago y no tomé en cuenta que la formulación estaba mal hecha.

Comment: Me disculpo y me tomaré el trabajo de leer los manuales debidamente.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Consecutivos, sin solaparse**

```
import re

frase = "Mientras sufria de sarampion asaba nueces en el magosto"

regex = "s.*?a.*?r.*?a.*?m.*?a.*?g.*?o"
saramagos = len(re.findall(regex,frase,re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL))

print(saramagos)   #  =>  1
```

Usando la expresión regular, donde `.*?` coincide con cualquier cantidad de caracteres (lo menos posible). [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) devuelve todas las coincidencias como una lista, y `len()` te da la cantidad.

---

---

**Aceptando coincidencias solapadas** (como `sarasarasaramagomagomago`)

```
import re

frase = "sarasarasaramagomagomago"

regex = "(?=s.*?a.*?r.*?a.*?m.*?a.*?g.*?o)"
saramagos = len(re.findall(regex,frase,re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL))

print(saramagos)   #  =>  3
```

Es la misma expresión que la anterior, pero no consume las coincidencias encontradas por usar un lookahead `(?=...)`, entonces permite solapamientos.

Comment: Revisa tu respuesta. Prueba con "sarasarasaramagomagomago".

Comment: @CandidMoe en ningún lugar dice que solapen, por más que sea sencillo tomarlo así, del ejemplo en la pregunta interpretaría que no

Comment: @CandidMoe agregué el caso a pedido tuyo ;-)

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con repsonder preguntas pobremente formuladas.

Comment: Te lo agradezco!

Comment: @Pollo Gracias, había investigado mucho regex, pero no encontré el patrón correcto para hacer lo que quería.

Answer (score -1):

Una solución es pasar buscando el cameo dentro del texto. Cuando se detecta una cameo, se saca esa parte del texto, y se repite la búsqueda con el texto restante, hasta no encontrar ninguna nueva ocurrencia.

```
def buscar_cameo(texto, cameo):
    cuenta = 0  # Numero total de ocurrencias encontradas
    hits = 1    # Numero de ocurrencias encontradas en ultima iteracion.

    while hits:   # Buscar una y otra vez mientras se encuentre algo.
        hits = 0  # Usamos hits para detectar encontradas en un ciclo.
        j = 0     # Indice sobre cameo.
        descartados = [] # Letras del texto que podrían ser cameo.

        for letra in texto:
            if cameo[j] == letra:
                j += 1
                if j == len(cameo): # Encontramos un cameo completo.
                    j = 0           # Reiniciar para buscar otro.
                    hits += 1       # Otro cameo encontrado en este ciclo.
            else:
                # Guardar letras que no sirven para una posterior búsqueda.
                descartados.append(letra)

        cuenta += hits
        # Crear un nuevo texto a partir de las letras descartadas para
        texto = "".join(descartados)

    return cuenta
```

**Comprobación**

```
tests = [
"Mientras sufria de sarampion asaba nueces en el magosto",
"Mientras sara el mago sufria  de sarampion asaba nueces en el magosto",
"Mientras sufria de sarampion asaba nueces en la magusta",
"sarasarasaramagomagomago"
]

for test in tests:
    x = buscar_cameo(test, "saramago")
    print(f"{x} ocurrencias en {test}")
```

produce

```
1 ocurrencias en Mientras sufria de sarampion asaba nueces en el magosto
2 ocurrencias en Mientras sara el mago sufria  de sarampion asaba nueces en el magosto
0 ocurrencias en Mientras sufria de sarampion asaba nueces en la magusta
3 ocurrencias en sarasarasaramagomagomago
```

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con repsonder preguntas pobremente formuladas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme!